# Adding Images to Wicked_pdf cover (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to create a cover page that has an image

Using wicked_pdf the cover just renders the absolute path of the image.   Any help greatly appreciated.

Here's the code snippet in the controller

```
      format.pdf do
      render pdf: "MNAZ_Directory", template: '/members/directory.pdf.erb',
              :cover =>'/members/cover.pdf.erb',

              :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?,
              :orientation => 'landscape', 
              :layout => 'pdf',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `cover.pdf.erb` file

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag('foo') %>
```

Comment: I've added the tag but :cover =>'/members/cover.pdf.erb', just shows the absolute path of cover.pdf.erg

Comment: try `:cover =>wicked_pdf_image_tag('foo')` directly.

Comment: That returns an error - undefined method `wicked_pdf_image_tag'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding [`render_to_string()`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string). Please see the sample code below.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf do 
    render  pdf: "MNAZ_Directory",  
            template: '/members/directory.pdf.erb',
            layout: "pdf",
            cover: render_to_string("/members/cover.pdf.erb"),
            show_as_html: params[:debug].present?
  end
end
```